# Can I visualize a voxel_grid on RViz?

Tags: navigation, rviz, costmap-2d, plugin, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Costmap_2D publishes voxel_grid (type costmap_2d/VoxelGrid) when publish_voxel_map parameter is set to true, but I cannot find the proper display on RViz. I suppose I need to install the appropriate plugin, but I cannot find it.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62360/can-i-visualize-a-voxel_grid-on-rviz?/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no appropriate plugin to my knowledge. You could write one, or you could use the costmap_markers node provided in the costmap_2d package.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1